# Hide one form when other button is clicked on (two buttons, two forms) (PHP/HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

I currently have two buttons, each displays a different form. I also have the buttons so that when you click on it once, it'll show the form, and if you click on it again, it'll hide the form.

**WHAT I WANT IT TO DO:**
I'm trying to get it so that if one form is already shown and I click on the button for the OTHER form, the one that is currently showing will hide and the OTHER one will show.

Here's what I thought would work, but if one of the form is shown and I click on the button for the other form, nothing happens.

```html
<script>
    function show(x, y){
        if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == "none" && document.getElementById(y).style.display != "none"){
            document.getElementById(x).style.display == "block";
            document.getElementById(y).style.display == "none";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById(x).style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<form>
    <button type = "button" onclick = 'show("searchForm", "insertForm");'>Perform Search</button>
    <button type = "button" onclick = 'show("insertForm", "searchForm");'>Insert Data</button>
</form>
    
<form id = "searchForm" value "search" style = "display: none;" action = "test2.php" method = "post">

    <!-- My code -->
  
</form>

<form id = "insertForm" style = "display: none;" action = "test2.php" method = "post">
  
    <!-- My code -->
      
</form>
```

I'm sure it's some really silly mistake I'm making. Can anyone help me figure this out and explain what I'm doing wrong and what I should be doing instead? Thanks!

Comment: Please show what is calling show

Comment: Invest in learning `jQuery`.  I was once afraid of `jQuery` but I finally gave up and just started to use it.  It is very clean and easy to use and the support on the web (and SO :-) is fantastic.

Comment: I will try to learn jQuery! But for the time being, I'd like to stick with Javascript because I've been working on this for some time and don't want to switch around too much. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3):

You are doing comparisons `==` in your `if`, and need to use an assignment `=`

```
if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == "none" && document.getElementById(y).style.display != "none"){
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "block";
                                             ^
    document.getElementById(y).style.display = "none";
                                             ^
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I must've been lazy and just copied and pasted the code from the condition in the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty small mistake..

document.getElementById(x).style.display **=** "block";
            document.getElementById(y).style.display **=** "none";

You are using equals operator instead of the assignment operator.

Comment: Oh wow... I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you want to use, try to touch DOM as few times as possible.

```
function show(x, y){
    var x, y;   // function scope vars

    // search for elements just once
    x = document.getElementById(x);
    y = document.getElementById(y);

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);   // just to show if you are getting elems you really want

        if(x.style.display == "none" && y.style.display != "none"){
            x.style.display = "block";
            y.style.display = "none";
        }
        else if(x.style.display == "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PHP, HTML, and Javascript so I'm not sure what you mean by DOM. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: @wuv1 [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM), it is the API you use to access and manipulate elements on the page.  If you are interested in more info about how the DOM works and some history on how it came to be, Douglas Crockford's talk [An Inconvenient API - The Theory of the DOM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs) is quite interesting.

Comment: @wuv1: Search for elements just once. Put elems in local variables and keep them in closures if needed. Benefits: less typing, more readable code, less chance to oversee something, less cpu cycles, less mem usage, faster code.... At the end, free unneeded elems in closures `x = y = null;` to avoid cross reference leaks.